# Find time difference between 2 times using moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a requirement to find the difference between 2 times(times in HH:MM:SS) format.

Need to get the difference in seconds.

```
var a = moment('21:04:59');
var b = moment('21:04:00');

a - b = 59 seconds
```

I have tried following 
Its worked for me with date time format, but not time filed alone.

```
var a = moment('2016-06-06T20:30:59');
var b = moment('2016-06-06T20:30:00');

console.log(a.diff(b, 'seconds')) // 59 seconds
```

Comment: Without a date, how do you know those times are 59 seconds apart?

Comment: have a look at @pranal patev answer, he's right

Answer (score 2):

you have to pass time like following in `moment`

```
var a = moment({
  h: 21,
  m: 04,
  s: 59
});
var b = moment({
  h: 21,
  m: 04,
  s: 00
});
```

**OUTPUT**
`console.log(a.diff(b, 'seconds'))` // **59 seconds**

Comment: The code in your answer works, but the OP has a string input, so he needs to split first input string into parts and then use the given code. Note that moment has a [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) constructor that should be used to parse string that are not in ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

In core, moment.js doesn't have support for time-only data. Even if you provide time-only data, it will try to store "today" as date.

But still you can do that.

**Legal Way**

```
var a = moment('21:04:59', 'HH::mm::ss');
var b = moment('21:04:50', 'HH::mm::ss');

alert(a-b); // returns miliseconds
```

**Tricky Alternative**

```
var dummyDate = '2016-05-05T'; // any date
var a = moment(dummyDate + '21:04:59');
var b = moment(dummyDate + '21:04:00');
console.log(a.diff(b, 'seconds'))
```

Comment: Please note that there is no `ii` token in [moment parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), you should use `ss` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to add the right format (`'HH:mm:ss'`) when parsing your string into moment object.

Your code gives a *Deprecation warning* because you are trying to parse a string that is not in a known ISO 8601 format. As the [documentation states](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

Note that, since you are not providing info about the day part, moment creates an object with the current date, month, and year.

Here a working example:

```js
var a = moment('21:04:59', 'HH:mm:ss');
var b = moment('21:04:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
console.log(a.diff(b, 'seconds'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Funny thing: I gave you a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545487/4131048) a little time ago