# Moment is time between 2 times, regardless of date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to figure out how to do a simple IF statement, to figure out if the provided date is between 08:00 and 20:15, regardless of the date

```
var obj = { "Date/Time": "2018-09-30 23:51:09" };

const date = moment(obj['Date/Time']).format("HH:mm:ss");
const start_time = "08:00:00";
const end_time = "20:15:00";

if (moment(date).isBetween(start_time, end_time)) {
  console.log("yes")
}
```

My code above though fails with the following error:

> ```
> Error at Function.createFromInputFallback
> (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js:17:482)
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778205/find-time-difference-between-2-times-using-moment-js.

Comment: Is it possible that start and end time are on opposite sides of midnight e.g. 20:00 and 04:00?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find time difference between 2 times using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778205/find-time-difference-between-2-times-using-moment-js)

Comment: The midnight part is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @SalmanA!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all three *strings* are in `HH:mm:ss` format you can simply compare them as strings:

```
var date       = "23:51:09";
var start_time = "08:00:00";
var end_time   = "20:15:00"; 
if (start_time <= date && date <= end_time) {
    console.log("yes");
}
```

And if there is a possibility of having midnight between start and end time then:

```
var date       = "23:51:09";
var start_time = "20:00:00";
var end_time   = "04:00:00"; 
if (
    (start_time <= end_time && (start_time <= date && date <= end_time)) ||
    (start_time >  end_time && (start_time <= date || date <= end_time))
) {
    console.log("yes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to construct the moment object correctly using `moment(string, string)` constructor in the `if` expression since the date string is not in ISO format.

Secondly, you can construct the `start_time` and `end_time` as moment objects as well, so that you can directly compare the time values of the three objects. See the demo below:

```js
var obj = {
  'Date/Time': '2018-09-30 09:51:09'
}

const date = moment(obj['Date/Time']).format("HH:mm:ss");
const start_time = moment("08:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss');
const end_time = moment("20:15:00", 'HH:mm:ss');

if (moment(date, 'HH:mm:ss').isBetween(start_time, end_time)) {
  console.log("yes")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like yyou will need to get the time for start and end with a moment commpatible time.

```
const start_time = moment(obj['Date/Time']).hour(8).startOf('hour');
const end_time = moment(obj['Date/Time']).hour(20) minute(15).startOf('minute');

if (moment(date).isBetween(start_time, end_time)) {
    console.log('WIN!');
}
```

if you are still getting the error it will be that the format of the date is not what moment it looking for and you will need to tell it the format with the 2nd arg for `moment(DATE, FORMAT)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
    const date = new Date('2018-09-30 23:51:09');
    const start_time = new Date('2018-09-30 8:00:00');
    const end_time = new Date('2018-09-30 20:15:00');     

    if (start_time<date && date<end_time) {
      console.log('yes');
    }
```

Comment: Because a timestamp of '2018-09-30 23:51:09' is not a format supported by ECMA-262 and returns an invalid Date in some implementations. :-(