# Moment.js return invalid date in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, momentjs

I have this code:

```
a = moment(a).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
b = moment(b).add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

     } while (a !== moment(new Date($('.finish-' + id).val())).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

In chrome and other browsers, it's okay, but safari returns invalid data and therefore while loop infinite...

Comment: You should always use format along with date string in moment. Also, you do not need `new Date(...)` Just try `moment($('.finish-' + id).val(), inputFormatType).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @Rajesh thank you very much, it's helped me, but 
could you explain why my code did not work in safari?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js gives Invalid date in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541196/moment-js-gives-invalid-date-in-firefox)