# moment.js and Safari Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, momentjs

After days so struggling with Safari and IOS devices, I installed [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to my project thinking all the problems would be solved. When I load my site in Safari or IOS devices, I see `_Invalid Code_` where the time and dates should be. I've tried multiple things from other stackoverflow question but I can't seem to get anywhere.

```
json[i]["Demo_Start"] = new Date(json[i]["Demo_Start"]);
  var startDemo = json[i]["Demo_Start"]
  var startResult = moment(startDemo).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
  json[i]["Demo_Start"] = startResult;
```

Comment: What is the original value of `json[i]["Demo_Start"]`? Are there messages in the browser console?

Comment: What is the value of `json[i]["Demo_Start"]`? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34541196/4131048) for similar issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue  with the value `moment(2017-03-12 18:30:00 +1100).format('MMMM Do YYYY')`