# Javascript : Invalid Date shown in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, date, firefox, momentjs

I'm getting a metadata from rails server and I want to show the attribute  image date_time_original  in angularjs side :

The rails serializer return the metadata:

```
 module Api::V1::Angular
    class MediumSerializer < BaseSerializer
      attributes :src, :mediumable_type, :mediumable_id, :comment, :is_archived, :order, :metadata
```

and here the js method :

```
getDateTimeOriginal: =>
      if @metadata? and @metadata.date_time_original?
        dateTime = new Date(@metadata.date_time_original)
        moment(dateTime).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM')
```

haml side :

```
.col-md-6.thumbnail{ ng_repeat: "img in fragment.media() | notArchived | orderBy:'order'" }
           %img.pointer{ ng_src: "{{ img.contentUrl() }}", ng_click:'openCarouselModal(img)' }
           %p {{ img.comment }}
           %p.photo-date
            {{ img.getDateTimeOriginal() }}
```

In google chrome it work perfectly but it did not in Firefox !

Comment: Which is the value `@metadata.date_time_original`? Anyway, take a look at this question [Moment.js gives Invalid date in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34541196/4131048).

Comment: Thanks VincenzoC for your answer , i did a console log for you and this the value of @metadata.date_time_original : **2018-05-09 09:46:47 UTC**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply resolve this issue by specifying `dateTime` current date format.

ex: `moment(dateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM')`

And if you know the format of `@metadata.date_time_original` no need to use `new Date()`. Only thing need to specify the current date format of `@metadata.date_time_original`

ex: `moment(@metadata.date_time_original, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM')`