# why chrome and firefox give different output in moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

could you please tell me why I am getting different output in chrome and firefox

code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/1wIvVISmgEqcRNnAD971?p=preview

execute this line

```
console.log(moment(moment("09-Feb-1983").format('DD-MMM-YYYY'), 'DD-MMM-YYYY', true).isValid())
```

Chrome gives: `true`
Firefox gives: `false`

Comment: _"Deprecation warning: **value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format**. moment construction **falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions**. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release."_

Comment: @Andreas so how i will solve this

Comment: Use a proper format or try to find a suitable format string: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: it is already DD-MMM-YYYY format string

Comment: A suitable format string _for parsing_ the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js gives Invalid date in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541196/moment-js-gives-invalid-date-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are using a format that momentjs does not parse by default, so it fallsback to the native Date implementation. Which Chrome supports but not Firefox. You can see this if you put `new Date("09-Feb-1983")` in Chrome it will give you a date but in Firefox it will say invalid date.
All you need is to help moment js by giving the format as second parameter.

```
console.log(moment(moment("09-Feb-1983", 'DD-MMM-YYYY' /* <= This was added!*/).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'), 'DD-MMM-YYYY', true).isValid())
```