# Moment.js return RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, date, momentjs

I'm using **moment.js** in my **React** app and website.
For a reason I unknow, my code work perfectly on *Chrome* and *Opera*, but not on *Firefox*.

I'm using this code :

```
moment(new Date().getDate(), "MM-DD-YYYY").format("MM-DD-YYYY")
```

Or this code :

```
moment(MY_DATE, "MM-DD-YYYY").format("MM-DD-YYYY") 
moment(MY_DATE).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
```

And Firefox return me always the same error :

> **RangeError: Invalid time value**

The console show me a normale date ("04-24-2020") on all navigator, exept Firefox

Someone has the problem too ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment.js gives Invalid date in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541196/moment-js-gives-invalid-date-in-firefox)

Comment: @aytek not really, I try this and didn't work