# Format moment reactjs DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

```
if (vStatus === 1) {
            let result = vResponse.data.Output.Result.map((item) => {
              return {
                ...item,
                Datetime: moment(item.Datetime).format(
                  "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"
                ),
                Tee: moment(item.Tee).format(
                  "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"
                ),
              };
            });
            SetResult(result);
            SetTotalPageValue(vResponse.data.Output.TotalPage);
            SetStartDateValue(vResponse.data.Input.StartDate.Value);
            SetEndDateValue(vResponse.data.Input.EndDate.Value);
            SetStatusIdValue(vResponse.data.Input.StatusId.Value);
            SetStatusId(vResponse.data.Input.StatusId);
          }
        })
```

Im Expect 12-Nov-2022 On Mozilla but why output UI 12-Nov--2022 and output on chrome is normal 12-Nov-2022

and then im trying export with react-csv output on my excel is 12-Nov--2022 <- Mozilla
Chrome version 11/12/2022

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545487/12715723). Just give the initial format of the source date on the second parameter like this:

```js
moment('2022-11-12','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Demo:

```js
let item = {};
item.Datetime = '2022-11-12'
console.log(moment(item.Datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```